# Ideas for Ranking of search results of a location-based activity app [iOS & Android]

Tags: database-design, gps, google-places-api, backend

I'm developing a simple ios app where users can perform activities(review, checkin) on locations provided by Google Places API. I store id, name and coordinates of a location in app's backend(on Server) after an activity has been performed on it for the first time. Currently I've two tables in my database Activity & Location.

Now I want to show these locations with activities to users on a Map. The users can see location around their current location or they can search locations from a city. I also want to allow users to search locations in a certain viewport like AirBnB or Fourthsquare. Currently my search query takes center coordinates & radius and returns all available locations which are on my server.

My question is how to rank my locations in search results according to current map zoom. In AirBnb app if you select a city then it shows X number of rooms available but on Map it doesn't shows you all locations at once but when you zoom in then you see more locations. How can I achieve that because when you zoom in then search radius is decreased but number of locations on map actually increased?

I know that on map you can show huge number of pins(locations) in group pin form and when you zoom in then this group pin is changed into individual pins but I don't want to fetch large number of pins from server. I just want to show locations which are best suited according to current zoom level.

Any Ideas on how other apps do this thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some statistical information (user rating, number of visits, etc.) you can display for example top 200 points by that metric.

This way you will limit the number of rows when the map is unzoomed, yet still displaying the most valuable points in the area (limited to radius or square `X-X * Y-Y` coordinates).

On the other hand, when you zoom in, more and more points get displayed until all of them are on the map.